# column to aligned properly in a row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

i am working on this layout where i have like large-8 columns and largee 4 columns.
Now i am repeating large 8 columns like a list horizontally but somehow large 4 column shifts with large 8 ones.
[image]

**The hello column shifts.**
i have a fiddle at my personal website so you can take a look at live example here.
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
thanks.
[**LINK**](http://beautifulsoftwares.com/question/)
Thanks.

Comment: @Filly i am confused. can you throw me quick code.thanks

Comment: @Filly yeah its right but for small the Hello column is in center but i want it at the end bottom.Please help me.post an answer. t ha n ks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your rows inside the 8 large. try nest them as good as you can

```
 <div class="row bordered ">


    <div class="large-8 columns  singleSearchedItem">

        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="columns large-6  small-6 ">
                <div class="columns large-11 small-11 ">

                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" class="thumbImagesForSearchResults" alt="Alternate Text" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Car Side Stats -->
            <div class="columns large-6 small-6 ">
                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <h6 class="carNameForSearch">Mercedes Benz 600 Blue Edition</h6>
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <p class="cardetailsPara">Off-road Vehicle/Pickup Truck, Used vehicle, Automatic transmission, Diesel, 190 kW (258 PS), Fuel consumption combined: 6.8 l/100 km</p>
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <div class="small-4 columns ">
                        <img src="img/milage.png" /><span class="specText">5423 KMS</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns">
                        <img src="img/date.png" /><span class="specText">12/2012</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns"><span class="specText">$33,0000</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <!-- Item -->
            <div class="columns large-6  small-6 ">
                <div class="columns large-11 small-11 ">

                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" class="thumbImagesForSearchResults" alt="Alternate Text" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Car Side Stats -->
            <div class="columns large-6 small-6 ">
                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <h6 class="carNameForSearch">Mercedes Benz 600 Blue Edition</h6>
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <p class="cardetailsPara">Off-road Vehicle/Pickup Truck, Used vehicle, Automatic transmission, Diesel, 190 kW (258 PS), Fuel consumption combined: 6.8 l/100 km</p>
                    <hr />
                </div>

                <div class="columns large-12 small-12">
                    <div class="small-4 columns ">
                        <img src="img/milage.png" /><span class="specText">5423 KMS</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns">
                        <img src="img/date.png" /><span class="specText">12/2012</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-4 columns"><span class="specText">$33,0000</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Right Search -->
    <div class="large-4 small-12 columns bordered">
        <div class="large-11 large-offset-1 columns bordered">
            <h3>hELLO</h3>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below layout/code. Also share this code in fiddle so we can help you better and understand your issue.

```
<div class="row bordered ">

    <!-- Item -->
    <div class="large-8 columns bordered singleItem">
        <div class="columns large-6  small-6 bordered">
            <div class="columns large-11 small-11 centered">

                <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Car Side Stats -->
        <div class="columns large-6 small-6 bordered">
            <div class="columns large-12 small-12"><h6>Mercedes Benx 600</h6></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Right Search -->
    <div class="large-4 small-12 columns bordered">
        <div class="large-11 large-offset-1 columns bordered">
            <h3>hELLO</h3>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-8 columns bordered singleItem" style="float: left;">
        <div class="columns large-6  small-6 bordered">
            <div class="columns large-11 small-11 centered">

                <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text">

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Car Side Stats -->
        <div class="columns large-6 small-6 bordered">
            <div class="columns large-12 small-12"><h6>Mercedes Benx 600</h6></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Endd Right Search -->
</div>
```

EDIT:

Possible fix to comment, for the **hello** div that is coming at the bottom on window resize.

Could you please check your CSS @media queries. I feel it have something to do with these css class small-6, large-6, small-12. This is just a suggestion after having a quick look at the link that you provided in the comment.

Comment: @hirem the layout looks fine but in small size the hello column comes in center of both car columns. i wanted that in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You have Two Large-8 div one after the other inside a row which stacks them vertically.

Have your large-4 div between the large-8 divs

```
    <body>

    <div class="row bordered ">

        <!-- Item -->
        <div class="large-8 columns bordered singleItem">
            <div class="columns large-6  small-6 bordered">
                <div class="columns large-11 small-11 centered">

                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text">

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Car Side Stats -->
            <div class="columns large-6 small-6 bordered">
                <div class="columns large-12 small-12"><h6>Mercedes Benx 600</h6></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="large-4 small-12 columns bordered">
            <div class="large-11 large-offset-1 columns bordered">
                <h3>hELLO</h3>


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="large-8 columns bordered singleItem">
            <div class="columns large-6  small-6 bordered">
                <div class="columns large-11 small-11 centered">

                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="Alternate Text">

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Car Side Stats -->
            <div class="columns large-6 small-6 bordered">
                <div class="columns large-12 small-12"><h6>Mercedes Benx 600</h6></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Right Search -->


        <!-- Endd Right Search -->
    </div>




    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Ram now the laout looks like zag.!

Comment: @designerNProgrammer ZAG!?

Comment: yeah like the second car columns shifted.to a bit right.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer just copied html and checked they are fine no shift in columns.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `large-4` column between the `large-8 columns`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTWgL/).

So basically what's happening it's that both `large-8` columns are floated left, but their widths summed up are bigger than the screen width, so they stack one after the other, instead of side-by-side (The part "Problems with Floats" explains the problem [here](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)).

Finally, the `large-4` stays aside the last `large-8` column, because the `large-8` column is placed before in the HTML.

I'll explain it with widths:

Your current HTML is `width: 66.6667%` -> `width: 66.6667%` -> `width: 33.3333%`. Because 66.66% + 66.66% > 100% (that is, wider than the actual screen), the second `width: 66.6667%` is pushed down. And the `width: 33.3333%` column can't ignore the presence of the previous column, so it stays pushed down as well instead of going all the way up.

To fix this, the order in the HTML should be `width: 66.6667%` -> `width: 33.3333%` -> `width: 66.6667%`. 66.66 + 33.33 <= 100, so it's OK, "we" can stay side by side, and the last column is pushed down.

Also, there is a Foundation CSS rule floating the last column to the right, you should override it (like I did in the JSFiddle):

```
[class*="column"] +[class*="column"]:last-child {
    float: left;
}
```

### Edit after your comment

Having the `large-4` column at the end in small screen is trickier, but you can use absolute positioning like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1026px) {
    .row.bordered {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 46px; /* This is the height of the "Hello" bar! When you add more content and the sidebar gets taller, you should increase this value! */
    }

    .large-4 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Check the new JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTWgL/1/).